# Click anchor tag link on enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have an anchor tag like

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="clicking" data-bind="click: $root.enterLocation" href="#">Continue</a>
```

It's inside a pop-up. I need to click on this link on pressing enter key. I have tried the following code but it did not work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(document).keyup(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13){
      $("#clicking").trigger('click');     
    }
  })
});
```

Not sure why the functionality is not working. I have used click function also with same result.Its working correctly on mouse click. I need to make it work automatically on enter press.

Following code is working fine in Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      document.getElementById("clicking").click();   
    }
  });
});
```

How to make this work on Chrome?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `event.which`, not `keyCode`?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dc9YM/ Just to clarify, the link works when you click on it normally with the mouse, but not when you press enter? Are you sure the page has focus when you press enter?

Comment: @Juhana You're probably using a browser that uses `keyCode`, so that's fine, but what about `charCode`? Save the hassle of using either and just use the normalized property `event.which` that jQuery adds to provide a general, correct keycode for the event.

Comment: @juhana i have a textfield on dat popup which i need to focus fast. On enter press i need to click on that link...

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you're using `event.keyCode`, which isn't always used in all browsers. Some browsers use `event.charCode` or even a different `event.which`, which may be supported by what you're using. Anyways, the normal way to get the keycode from the event with jQuery is to use `event.which`.

jQuery normalizes the `event` object passed to the event handler and fixes "problems" like this so that you don't have to worry. At the same time, it seems that it copies over some of the original event's properties ("Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object." - from the jQuery API docs). That's probably why it's "working" for the other people commenting/answering. The `event` parameter passed to the handler has been generated/normalized by jQuery and will have everything you need, using the right properties. The correct way though, is to use `event.which` to get a normalized keycode for the event. http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $("#clicking").trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egzsf/
It works perfectly I only added a fallback for Internet Explorer.

What does your popup looks like? Maybe it's an iFrame, that would be a logical explaination.

Code:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="clicking" data-bind="click: $root.enterLocation" onclick="alert('test')" href="#">Continue</a>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
        $("#clicking").trigger('click');       

        }
    })
});​
```

**Better alternative is using e.which**

Comment: That is no "fallback for Internet Explorer". There's no reason to use any fallbacks for any browser because jQuery takes care of this automatically. This won't help anyways, because the problem is probably the absence of `event.charCode` which also isn't necessary, because jQuery normalizes both into `event.which` . The two properties are `keyCode` and `charCode`, so I bet the OP is using a browser that uses `charCode` but is expecting `keyCode`. Either way, you should use `event.which`

Comment: I didn't knew jQuery does this automaticcly. Also there is no browser that does support charCode but not keyCode. Internet Explorer 7 and 8 use window.event.keyCode. Internet Explorer 9 uses e.keyCode and Firefox / Chrome also use e.keyCode.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Anyways, `charCode` is only used by NS/Firefox and may or may not be filled in, so you it's something you need to check for. Either way, you don't need to do any of this type of checking thanks to jQuery

Comment: Nevermind English is not my main language I didn't quite understand what you were trying to say. Now I do.

Comment: @Sanjib Karmakar: event.keyCode is also working in Chrome, see: http://jsfiddle.net/vEKAK/

Comment: document.getElementById("clicking").click();  working in Firefox not in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code can help you .try it
Code:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="clicking" onclick="window.location='index.php'" href="#">Continue</a>

$(function(){
  $('body').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){  
      $("#clicking").click();
    }
  })
});
```