# How to make an anchor tag active when pressing enter in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a search button which I would like to be executed not only when I click on it but also when I press enter so it would be easier to make searches. Im using jQuery mobile to display the search button, here's the HTML code:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="csr-popup-search" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a" style="margin-top:0px;padding-top:0px;min-width:330px">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:88%"><input type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" placeholder="Search..."/></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b ui-responsive" style="width:10%;padding-top:3px;">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true"  data-icon="search" onclick="ws.csr.search.run(this)">Search all</a></div>
        </div>
```

This is how it looks on my end:

[image: search button]

I know with buttons I just simply make it type="submit" but in this case this doesn't work since it is an anchor tag.

Comment: you might wanna check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797894/click-anchor-tag-link-on-enter-press

Comment: try this `$('#search-basic').on("keyup",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
        ws.csr.search.run(this)   ;
    
});
`

Comment: @Sushil thanks for your response, I put your code at the bottom of my html page wrapped by <script> but it doesn't get executed, is there anything else that I need to do so it gets executed?

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen on the document for a keypress. If the key was enter (key code 13), you can then call your ajax.

```
$(document).on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $("#id-of-a-tag").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, so, can I put my call inside of the do stuff just like how I have it right now? I mean this call: ws.csr.search.run(this)

Comment: you will need to select the input data. Updated the code.

Comment: It seems like it's getting called (I see that in chrome devtools but is doing nothing). No the same as when I click on the button.

Comment: this is the function that I want to tun after I press enter if that helps: http://pastie.org/private/msnmaiwy35spupyrzxchqg

Comment: that takes just the element not the value of the field. You need to pass in the 'a' tag and it should work as before

Comment: you mean pass the a tag inside of the ws.csr.search.run?

Comment: right, that function takes the 'a' tag as designated by the 'this'....... ws.csr.search.run($('#id-of-a-tag')); should work.

Comment: I had to do this `$(document).on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        document.getElementById("search-basic2").click();
    }
});` and add a name to the a tag element. Thanks for your help